# Do i need to rebuild my solution after changing anything in web.config?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

Like I changed my connection string to another ip address do I need to rebuild the whole solution/project? And what if I change anything else in it?

Comment: What error did you receive when you tried it?

Comment: Considering that `web.config` can be edited live on the production server which (hopefully) doesn't have VS installed at all, why would you think this?

Comment: Are changing the web.config of already deployed application?

Comment: @KennethK., there is no error, i just need to know do I need to rebuild my project everytime i make any changes in web.config

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, because i am a noob at all these things. And as I can see you are very experienced developer, could you tell me how to restart a site? do i need to click on application in IIS manager and select "restart" or i need to restart app pool too? or even instead of?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, well, i start it from IIS manager. I didn't use deployment feature in VS or anything like this

Comment: Any change that involves either the \bin folder or the web.config files causes an application reset in the server. All sessions would be ended and if the web.config was modified the values the code would read will be the modified ones. Do not that in the bin folder there is usually the dll of the result of the compilation

Comment: As a general advice, I would suggest always deploying/publishing when putting an application in a preproduction or production server. The reasons behind it are: a) Better performance b) It is easier to manage a dll's folder tahn many .aspx.cs files c) Anyone with access to the server could read those .cs files and maybe you dont want them to know how you do things.

Comment: If you are developing the project using VS and using IIS, you don't need to build the solution. When you change web.config the application needs to reset to get the updated values from config. That does not require rebuild, just refresh the browser. It will take little bit more time at first time to load but after that it will do fine.

Comment: @bradbury9, well, i am in the middle of debugging maybe? I am checking if my site works properly

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about `<compilation debug="true">`,So, you don't need to rebuild your solution/project.

This is about ASP.NET compilation rather than your regular project compilation. Whenever an ASP.NET application is started, unless it has been published precompiling it, ASP.NET engine will compile your user controls, code-behind code and other areas of your Web application during the first request to your Web site.

Answer (score 0):

No. But you need to replay/restart your project or restart your website from IIS to take effect the changes in your web.config.